# Fetching data from webservice and caching on iphone

Tags: iphone, caching

I want to access a webservice to fetch alot of data (e.g. product lists/details/search results) and display this.

Are there any best practices for this type of operations?

Performance-wise, is there any better way than retrieving, parsing and displaying text data on each request and maybe load images in the background? Are there any wise caching policies which may be applied?

Answer (score 1):

If I were doing something like this from the ground-up, here's what I'd do:

1. Have the web site post all the data in XML. Except for maybe the pictures - just have an XML field specify a URL for each picture. So, for example, say I was doing a product list.
2. Use NSXMLParser to both fetch and parse the XML data.
3. Use a separate NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: call to fetch the contents of each image, with the URL from the XML data
4. Write the XML data, (and the NSData image) to a database table with CoreData. Add a indexed timestamp field to the table.
5. You can now use the timestamp field to keep the newest "x" records in the database - and can purge the older ones if/when you need to.
6. Use the contents of the database table to populate a UITableView - or however else you want to present.
7. Make some sort of "next", "prev" or "update" fields in the UITableView to get more data from the web, if you need to display more data than is what is cached - or you want to update the data in the cache.

Comment: Unless you've got a good reason to use XML, it's better to use JSON. It uses less bandwidth, and it's trivial to parse JSON into native Foundation objects using open source frameworks, saving you from writing a whole bunch of XML parsing code. Also, it's usually not a good idea to add large blobs of data (such as images) to Core Data for performance reasons. Caching them as files is easy, and more performant.

Comment: There is already a comprehensive XML Parsing class built into iOS, that's not only already there for you to use - but also deal with the fetching of the data from the network - no "open source frameworks" to go get and integrate. I am 50/50 on your argument about not storing blobs in the database - a lot of map frameworks do this - but you *could* store them as discrete files like you suggest as well - and just have the DB record point to them.

Comment: this one is really good and give some clue, but it is theoretical post which make it least useful for a newbie. hope You can give some practical approach to this question: [connecting-to-server-retrieving-data-and-storing-that-on-local-database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5576079/connecting-to-server-retrieving-data-and-storing-that-on-local-database) Thank You