# Connecting to server, retrieving data, and storing that on local database

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite

This time it's not about local problem, I now have to connect to remote server and fetch information from there, and that information I want to store in my local database of an iPhone application. I don't have any clue of even how to start this process.
 Another issue is I need to retrive an Image too from given path and to store that image in my local folder.

Please help me with this.

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If fetching the information over HTTP is an option, I'd recommend you look into the excellent [ASIHTTPRequest](http://This%20is%20the%20third%20section%20of%20the%20script.) library. As for storing this information locally, take a look at Apple's [Core Data](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html) framework—support for this framework is built into Xcode.

Retrieving an image from a URL is fairly straightforward:

```
// Assuming imageURL is the image's URL as an NSURL.
UIImage *image = [UIImage initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL]];
```

You can then store this image in your application's documents folder or as raw data in core data.